# How to reset data in a field after changing selection in another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

I am working with ejTimePicker reference site:

http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/js/default.htm#!documents/createyourfirsttimep1.htm

I have two select boxes, say `textbox1` and `textbox2` which contain selected `times`.
I'm looking for a way to reset the time in `textbox2` when I select a different time in `textbox1`.

Sample code is here

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { id = "StartTime" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime,new { id = "EndTime" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)
    </div>
```

And javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var mintime = "6:00 AM";
 var maxtime = "11:00 PM";
 var minTimepicker;
 $(function () {
     $('#StartTime').ejTimePicker({
         minTime: mintime,
         maxTime: maxtime,
         interval: 60,
    });
      $('#EndTime').ejTimePicker({
          minTime: mintime,
          maxTime: maxtime,
          interval: 60,
       });
     });

  </script>
```

I tried many other way but with no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#StartTime').change(function(){
      $('#EndTime').val("");
    });
});
```

Comment: yes i tried but i have found no result at the end .

Comment: Change EditorFor to TextBoxFor and try

Comment: I changed the EditorFor to TextBoxFor but there is no result found.When i check in the Firebug then no change function hit when select the date from EditorFor or TextBoxFor .

Comment: Check my updated code, you may have to put the snippet withing $(function(){}); block

Comment: Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/yf0fLhr1/2/. Also make sure that your Text in start Time Actually changes. If you select the same date the date in EndTime will not change

Comment: Hello progrAmmar i got the solution by using the function : function selectedStartTime(sender) {

        var selDate = sender.value; // mentions the selected time.

        minTimepicker = $("#EndTime").data("ejTimePicker");// creating TimePicker object

        minTimepicker.setModel({ "minTime": selDate });// setting minTime property through setModel of TimePicker object.

    }

Answer (score 0):

Hello progrAmmar i got the solution by using the function given function :

```
    function selectedStartTime(sender) {

    var selDate = sender.value; // mentions the selected time.

    minTimepicker = $("#EndTime").data("ejTimePicker");// creating TimePicker object

    minTimepicker.setModel({ "minTime": selDate });// setting minTime property through setModel of TimePicker object.

}
```

But Stuck to add 1 hour in the second textbox.

Thanks